# Apache Spark visualization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Apache Spark and trying to learn visualization in Apache Spark/Databricks at the moment. If I have the following csv datasets;

Patient.csv

```
+---+---------+------+---+-----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| Id|Post_Code|Height|Age|Health_Cover_Type|Temperature|Disease_Type|Infected_Date|
+---+---------+------+---+-----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
|  1|     2096|   131| 22|                5|         37|           4|    891717742|
|  2|     2090|   136| 18|                5|         36|           1|    881250949|
|  3|     2004|   120|  9|                2|         36|           2|    878887136|
|  4|     2185|   155| 41|                1|         36|           1|    896029926|
|  5|     2195|   145| 25|                5|         37|           1|    887100886|
|  6|     2079|   172| 52|                2|         37|           5|    871205766|
|  7|     2006|   176| 27|                1|         37|           3|    879487476|
|  8|     2605|   129| 15|                5|         36|           1|    876343336|
|  9|     2017|   145| 19|                5|         37|           4|    897281846|
| 10|     2112|   171| 47|                5|         38|           6|    882539696|
| 11|     2112|   102|  8|                5|         36|           5|    873648586|
| 12|     2086|   151| 11|                1|         35|           1|    894724066|
| 13|     2142|   148| 22|                2|         37|           1|    889446276|
| 14|     2009|   158| 57|                5|         38|           2|    887072826|
| 15|     2103|   167| 34|                1|         37|           3|    892094506|
| 16|     2095|   168| 37|                5|         36|           1|    893400966|
| 17|     2010|   156| 20|                3|         38|           5|    897313586|
| 18|     2117|   143| 17|                5|         36|           2|    875238076|
| 19|     2204|   155| 24|                4|         38|           6|    884159506|
| 20|     2103|   138| 15|                5|         37|           4|    886765356|
+---+---------+------+---+-----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

And coverType.csv

```
+--------------+-----------------+
|cover_type_key| cover_type_label|
+--------------+-----------------+
|             1|           Single|
|             2|           Couple|
|             3|           Family|
|             4|       Concession|
|             5|          Disable|
+--------------+-----------------+
```

Which I've managed to load as DataFrames (Patient and coverType);

```
val PatientDF=spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("inferSchema","true")
  .option("nullValue","NA")
  .option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
  .option("mode","failfast")
  .option("path","/spark-data/Patient.csv")
  .load()

val coverTypeDF=spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("inferSchema","true")
  .option("nullValue","NA")
  .option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
  .option("mode","failfast")
  .option("path","/spark-data/covertype.csv")
  .load()
```

1. How do I generate a bar chart visualization to show the distribution of different Disease_Type in my dataset.
2. How do I generate a bar chart visualization to show the average Post_Code of each cover type with string labels for cover type.
3. How do I extract the year (YYYY) from the Infected_Date (represented in date (unix seconds since 1/1/1970 UTC)) ordering the result in decending order of the year and average age.

Answer (score 0):

To display charts natively with Databricks you need to use the display function on a dataframe.  For number one, we can accomplish what you'd like by aggregating the dataframe on disease type.

```
display(PatientDF.groupBy(Disease_Type).count())
```

Then you can use the charting options to build a bar chart, you can do the same for your 2nd question, but instead of .count() use .avg("Post_Code")

For the third question you need to use the year function after casting the timestamp to a date and an orderBy.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
display(PatientDF.select(year(to_timestamp("Infected_Date")).alias("year")).orderBy("year"))
```